# qgis2threejs borehole data displayed upside down

Tags: qgis-plugins

in qgis2threejs I followed the instructions of a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmcGRrQmXQI). Everything worked but the borehole data is displayed upside down.

Is there a setting that need to be changed?

I would like to avoid shuffling my data upside down beforehand. Unfortunately it is not possible to rotate more than 180°.

[image: correct display]

[image: incorrect display]

Comment: In elevation data the numbers usually grow upwards from the surface but with borehole data I guess it is the opposite. If this is the case I suggest to change the sign of the Z coordinate of your data. I do not know if it is possible to make it by using a virtual layer in QGIS without editing your source data physically. Have a try.

Comment: I tried it with a '-' before the Z coordinate or/and the depth coordinate. The result was the same unfortunately.